# why eBPF programs need some passes to get jited code?

Tags: linux-kernel, jit, ebpf

I'm new to eBPF, I am reading the source code from linux kernel tree `arch/x86/net/bpf_jit_comp.c`. I noticed there are some passes needed for the final jited image. I'm very confused about this. Toturial says **JITed image shrinks with every pass and the loop iterates until the image stops shrinking.** Could you give me an example? As far as I am concerned, eBPF jit is a one-to-one mapping, how can the image shrink?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for [qmo](https://github.com/qmonnet) .Maybe [this](https://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1506.0/03995.html) can be helpful. I think this is due to the x86 instruction length is not fixed and some passes are needed for relocation.